# How to implement a double type method

Tags: java

Implement a method that is passed by two double type numbers, prints out their total and doesn't return anything. Guys how does this look now???

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Tutorial1 {

```
public static void main1(double num1, double num2)
{
    double numb1=3.5;
    double numb2=3.4;
    double total = numb1 + numb2;
    Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println(total);
    numb1 = reader.nextInt();
    numb2 = reader.nextInt();

}
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at [Classes and Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html), [Defining Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) and [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Comment: Have you ever written a method? It should look something like this: `public void someMethod(double firstNum, double secondNum) {}`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what u want well try this hope helps to u

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MyFirstJavaProgram {

    public static void main(String []args) {

       main1(3.65,2.85);
    }
    public static double main1 (double numb12, double numb21){
    int numb1 = 0, numb2 = 0;
    int total = numb1 + numb2;
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter two integers: ");
     numb1 = reader.nextInt();
     numb2 = reader.nextInt();
    System.out.println(total+numb1+numb2);
    return total+numb1+numb2;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you may have helped me figure this thing out! take a look above.

Comment: I didnt understand that why u gave two parameters if u dont use them.U are taking input from user  so why are u declaring doucle if u use inpus from user .If u write what u want i can help more